# how to pass ohai hints through chef knife bootstrap command

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I need to disable the passwd plugin in my chef-client environment to avoid a FATAL error due to the large number of users.

The way I did for the local client is to add the following line to the client.rb file:

```
ohai[:disabled_plugins] = ["passwd"]
```

When bootstrapping a managed node, I would  like to have the same done through the knife bootstrap command to the managed node.  From the knife doc, here is the syntax:

> --hint HINT_NAME[=HINT_FILE]

An Ohai hint to be set on the target of the bootstrap. The hint is contained in a file and is formatted as JSON: `{"attribute":"value","attribute":"value"...}`. HINT_NAME is the name of the hint and HINT_FILE is the name of the hint file located at

> /etc/chef/ohai/hints/HINT_FILE.json

Use multiple --hint options in the command to specify multiple hints.

This is what I did:

On the chef workstation, under /etc/chef/ohai/hints/HINT_FIILE.jason, it has the following content:

```
{disabled_plugins:["passwd"]}
```

Here is the knife bootstrap command:

> knife bootstrap [managed_node_name] --hint disabled_plugins -sudo -x
>   user -P [password] -N "test_node"

When the command is completed, on the managed_node,  a new file is created:   /etc/chef/ohai/hints/disabled_plugins.json, with the following content:

> {}

This doesn't seem right...

Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have in your workstation (the one where you run knife) a file `/home/user/test.json` containing the following information

```
{ "foo": "bar" }
```

On the node (the server which will perform a chef-run) you'll find the file in `/etc/chef/ohai/hints/foo.json` using the following syntax:

```
$ knife bootstrap --hint foo=/home/user/test.json
```

This time `/etc/chef/ohai/hints/foo.json` on the node will contain

```
{ "foo": "bar" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the `--hint` option works the way you think, or is implied by the manual page.  It doesn't appear to read from the `/etc/chef/ohai/hints` directory on the Chef workstation, rather from the filename you specify to the `--hint` option.

This should work:

```
$ cat > myhint.json << EOF
{disabled_plugins:["passwd"]}
EOF
$ knife bootstrap --hint=myhint.json blah blah
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, created the myhint.json file on the chef workstation, and ran knife boostrap command.   

Upon completion, on the managed node, there is a file created as
/etc/chef/ohai/hints/myhint.json.json.

content of the file is:

{}

So it is not working yet.

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same issue and could not get hints to work properly as it doesn't seem to work in this particular way + lack of documenation samples.

In the end I just opted to edit the `chef-full.erb` which is the bootstrap default template use to generate the `client.rb`

To get the right file run this:

```
$ gem contents chef | grep bootstrap | grep full
/home/henryt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/chef-full.erb
```

Then `vim` that `chef-full.erb` file and add `ohai :disabled_plugins` line inside the `client.rb` here document (`cat > /etc/chef/client.rb <<'EOP'`)

```
Ohai::Config[:disabled_plugins] = [:Passwd]
```

My patch file:

```
--- ~me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/chef-full.erb.orig
   2016-07-22 00:53:33.689961205 -0700
+++ ~me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/chef-full.erb
2016-07-22 00:44:21.253493396 -0700
@@ -64,6 +64,7 @@

cat > /etc/chef/client.rb <<'EOP'
<%= config_content %>
+Ohai::Config[:disabled_plugins] = [:Passwd]
EOP

cat > /etc/chef/first-boot.json <<'EOP'
```

Now every time I bootstrap a machine the `client.rb` gets generated with that `ohai :disabled_plugins` line and I don't have to have a custom `client.rb` file.